# Get the child PID after system()

Tags: linux, exec, fork

As far as I understand, the `system()` call uses internally `fork()` and `exec()` but encapsulates them for a easier handling.

Is it possible to get the PID from the child process created with the `system()` call?

Aim: I want to be able to SIGINT any child process after a certain timeout. I could rebuild the `system()` function by using `fork()` and `exec()`. But all I need is the child's PID and perhaps there is shortcut by using `system()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, `system()` is a synchronous operation. This means it won't return until the child has exited, i.e. there is no valid PID for the child process when `system()` returns, since the child process no longer exists.

Comment: Yes - the process has gone when system() returns.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way (that I know of) when using `system()`. Besides, with `system()` there's the additional step of launching a shell which will execute your command, making this a tad more difficult. You're probably better off replacing it with `fork()` and `exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Solved it by:

```
int syspid,status;
pid_t ppid=getpid();
syspid=ppid+1

status=system(argv[1]); //here argv1 was another program;
```

This might not always work, but most of the time the system()'s PID is the parent's pid +1 (unless you have multiple forks).

Comment: This will only work in very specific circumstances. Specifically, it will only be correct if the `system()` call is the first thing your application does, AND there is nothing else spawning processes at the same time, AND your system assigns PIDs sequentially. None of these are guaranteed.

Comment: I completely agree. But it can help someone playing around until they learn fork() and exec() properly.

Answer (score -1):

However, there is a way of doing what you want via the /proc file system. You can go through process directories (directory names are PIDs) and check the "status" files. There's a PPid entry in each of them specifying the parent pid.

This way, if you get a "status" file which specifies the PID of your process as PPID, then its folder name in /proc file system is the value you are looking for.

Comment: unless another part of your program/library/etc has forked a program behind your back.  Replacing system(command) by { pid = fork + execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c",command,(char *)NULL); pid } is really simple and much more reliable, not to mention porable.